# bitwise_and DataFrame is not Printed. How to print only >1 values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, opencv, image-processing

I have cropped palm images in similar size and my task is to create a `DataFrame` for `bitwise_and`. Its image is printed correctly but `DataFrame` is not printed.

[image: df]

```
flat_data_arr=[]
target_arr=[]
#Give path of `your text`the parent-folder containing all category images folders.
datadir = (r'C:\\Users\\HRMini\\MyProjects\\PalmPredicion\\Male\\')
for i in Type_of_Risk:
    print(f'loading... Type_of_Risk : {i}')
    path=os.path.join(datadir,i)
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img1 = np.zeros((400,600,3), np.uint8)
        img1 = cv2.ellipse(img1, (280, 190), (290, 60),160, 0, 360, (255, 255, 255), -1)        
        img2 = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img))
        bitAnd = cv2.bitwise_and(img2, img1)        
        cv2.imshow("img1", img1)
        cv2.imshow("img2", img2)
        cv2.imshow('bitAnd', bitAnd)        
        cv2.imwrite('bitAnd.jpeg',bitAnd)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        flat_data_arr.append(bitAnd.flatten())
        target_arr.append(Type_of_Risk.index(i))
        print(f'loaded Type_of_Risk:{i} successfully')
flat_data=np.array(flat_data_arr)
target=np.array(target_arr)
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
df=pd.DataFrame(flat_data)
df['Target']=target
df
```

[image: output df of bitwise_and]

> img2 are cropped palm images and output bitwise_and DataFrame and target is Type_of_Risk read as 0,1,2,3.

[A cropped palm image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eH9x6.jpg)

Comment: @Markus. Thank you for edited correctly. I will try to post next one proper way.

Comment: Please try to focus your question to a minimal, reproducible example. We don't have input images, we don't know `Type_ofRisk`. We even don't know the output that you expect in contrast to the output that you have posted as screenshot. Please check [ask].

Comment: @Markus , Type_of_Risk=['No','Low','Medium','Critical'] read as Target 0,1,2,3 and output is dataframe of bitwise_and. I edited the question and added the img2. img1 is np.zeros((400,600,3), np.uint8).

Comment: Thank you for editing and adding some information. If you still need help, please phrase one clear question that includes the output that you want to achieve.

Comment: Do I get you right that all you are asking is how to filter for rows in `df` with a value greater zero in column `target`? That would be `df2 = df[df['target'] > 0]`.

Comment: @Markus, no change the _DataFrame_.

Comment: @Markus, I did it. _bitAnd = cv2.bitwise_and(img2, img1)_ , 
     _final_array=bitAnd[bitAnd >0 ]_ has is used to filter. Thank you for your help.